# sqlite3.OperationalError. SQLite thinks there is a ? mark but there is not

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to insert a Python dictionary into an SQLite3 database to store financial data from my brokerage. I want to learn Python and SQL to do this.

The dictionary I am trying to insert is:

```
data = {u'symbols': [{u'optionType': None, u'dividendDate': u'2017-12-15T00:00:00.000000-05:00', u'eps': 1.564, u'currency': u'CAD', u'prevDayClosePrice': 53.01, u'averageVol3Months': 641554, u'industrySubgroup': u'Gold', u'isTradable': True, u'hasOptions': True, u'optionDurationType': None, u'optionExpiryDate': None, u'symbolId': 6849, u'outstandingShares': 232319000, u'tradeUnit': 1, u'optionStrikePrice': None, u'pe': 33.9, u'lowPrice52': 46.91, u'industrySector': u'BasicMaterials', u'optionRoot': u'', u'description': u'AGNICO-EAGLE MINES', u'symbol': u'AEM.TO', u'securityType': u'Stock', u'dividend': 0.11, u'minTicks': [{u'pivot': 0, u'minTick': 0.005}, {u'pivot': 0.5, u'minTick': 0.01}], u'averageVol20Days': 635497, u'industryGroup': u'MetalsMining', u'optionContractDeliverables': {u'cashInLieu': 0, u'underlyings': []}, u'highPrice52': 68.76, u'yield': 1.06, u'listingExchange': u'TSX', u'isQuotable': True, u'optionExerciseType': None, u'marketCap': 12315230190, u'exDate': u'2017-11-30T00:00:00.000000-05:00'}]}
```

The code looks like:

```
data = data['symbols'][0]
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('sql/investment_databse.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            with conn:
                c.execute('''INSERT INTO daily_sec_data(optionType, dividendDate, eps, currency, prevDayClosePrice,
                         averageVol3Months, industrySubgroup, isTradable, hasOptions, optionDurationType,
                         optionExpiryDate, symbolId, outstandingShares, tradeUnit, optionStrikePrice,
                         pe, lowPrice52, industrySector, optionRoot, description,
                         symbol, securityType, dividend, minTicks, averageVol20Days,
                         industryGroup, optionContractDeliverables, highPrice52, yield, listingExchange,
                         isQuotable, optionExerciseType, marketCap, exDate)
                         VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,
                                ?,?,?,?,?,
                                ?,?,?,?,?,
                                ?,?,?,?,?,
                                ?,?,?,?,?,
                                ?,?,?,?,?,
                                ?,?,?,?)''',(data['optionType'], data['dividendDate'], data['eps'], data['currency'], data['prevDayClosePrice'],
                                data['averageVol3Months'], data['industrySubgroup'], data['isTradable'], data['hasOptions'], data['optionDurationType'],
                                data['optionExpiryDate'], data['symbolId'], data['outstandingShares'], data['tradeUnit'], data['optionStrikePrice'],
                                data['pe'], data['lowPrice52'], data['industrySector'], data['optionRoot'], data['description'],
                                data['symbol'], data['securityType'], data['dividend'], data['minTicks'], data['averageVol20Days'],
                                data['industryGroup'], data['optionContractDeliverables'], data['highPrice52'], data['yield'], data['listingExchange'],
                                data['isQuotable'], data['optionExerciseType'], data['marketCap'], data['exDate']))
                conn.commit()
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/michael/GoogleDrive/atomProjects/questrade/def_securities.py", line 114, in get_ftse_can_data
    data['isQuotable'], data['optionExerciseType'], data['marketCap'], data['exDate']))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 23 - probably unsupported type.
```

Line 114 is the second-to-last line of the above code.

Comment: Can I edit this to look better?

Comment: Please format your code as code (the `{}` button) not as quote.

Comment: Is that first section code? It's hard to tell with that formatting. You should use a code block rather than block quote.

Comment: How do I edit my post?

Comment: @MichaelCrowne Click on the 'edit' button at the bottom of your post and use the button with '{ }'  to format it as a code.

Comment: Thanks all, I think it is more readable now. The code block really helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
'minTicks': [{'pivot': 0, 'minTick': 0.005}, {'pivot': 0.5, 'minTick': 0.01}]
```

This is an array (containing two dictionaries). It cannot be stored in one of the [storage types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

If `minTicks` always has four values, you could extract them and store them in four columns. But to store an array of arbitrary size, you would need a separate table with an 1:N relationship to the main table.

Comment: Thank you so much. I removed the offending sub-dictionaries and the code works!